# Difference between Actions and Destination in Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

I would like to ask what is the difference between Action and Destination in the Android Navigation system?

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

I able to navigate screens using both (Actions and Destination). I need to know What is the usage of actions and destinations.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Though you can able to navigate screens using both actions and destination but there is difference.

**According to google navigation by actions has the following benefits over navigation by destination:**

1) You can visualize the navigation paths through your app

2) Actions can contain additional associated attributes you can set, such as a transition animation, arguments values, and backstack behavior

3) You can use the plugin safe args to navigate

For detail understanding follow this google [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation/#6) page.

Answer (score 0):

As this Google documentation say:

> - Destinations are the different content areas in your app.
> - Actions are logical connections between your destinations that    represent paths that users can take.

Or with other words `Destinations` are `Fragemnts` which can be used in the `NavHostFragment`, but the `Actions` are connections between these `Fragments`.

So, yes you can navigate to destinations in different ways and for more info you can check this link: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate, but `Actions` are created only from the `NavigationGraph` and you add them only when your flow is pre-defined and is not depend on the user behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The **Destination** describe where you go. In navigation graph you will see visual page that are **destinations**.

**Where `app:destination` use?**
It is using in action tag. But when you think about your bottom navigation. Then you can go other fragment without calling `app:destination` . So when you need to `click a button` to open a fragment then you need to set `app:destination`.

And action is that you are going one to another with a event this **action**. So you can see the arrow sign for both button click event and normal bottom navigation event. Both are **actions** 
 One is not need to write action tag another is need to write action tag (for button click or other event to go another page)

Same things for **Destination**.